# PS4 remote all of a sudden won't connect to PC Bluetooth

Tags: technical-issues, pc, ps4, ps-remote-play

I've connected both PS4 controllers to my PC. Now they will not connect.

I have tried:

- Downloaded *ds4windows* program
- Turned Bluetooth off and on
- Tried getting rid of the remote files
- Restarted the PC

...but the problem persisted.

*ds4windows* will find my remotes when directly plugged in with a USB cord, but it will not find my remotes with Bluetooth at all anymore.
My Bluetooth is a brand new bt500 and it will find and connect to my TV but not to the remotes.

Comment: You mean _controllers_ right? Not remotes?

Comment: When you look into your periferals in windows, do you see the controller in there? Also, could it be that there is something snatching the Controller signal before it gets to ds4 windows? Like Steam, for a few years, had controller support. And I know trying to run both a switch controller converter and the steam controller interface causes problems.

Comment: So basically, close steam and see if that fixes things. I havent used DS4 for years because Steam does it by itself now (and I do 99% of my PC gaming via a steam enabled game).